# How do I pass a full SFTP URL to the sftp command?

Tags: bash, command-line, sftp

I have a website that provides SFTP links in the format `sftp://user@host.com/path/to/file.zip`. To get this working via command line, I need to copy the link, and either run `sftp user@host` and then paste the path into the resulting shell:

```
$ > get /path/to/file.zip
```

Or I need to manipulate the URL into something like `sftp user@host.com:/path/to/file/zip`

Today I saw someone just run `sftp sftp://user@host.com/path/to/file.zip` and it worked just fine. When I do this it seems that sftp interprets the file path as part of the host and says

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname host.com/path/to/file.zip

How can I get it working such that I can just run this? `sftp sftp://user@host.com/path/to/file.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL syntax is supported by OpenSSH 7.7 and newer only.

As OpenSSH 7.7 is relatively new (2018-04-02), it is quite probable that you are using an older version.

Se also a related question [Using sftp like scp](https://superuser.com/q/1434225/213663).